# how to extract numbers from a string that starts with numbers in a column using python

Tags: python, regex, string, dataframe

I am new to Python and I have a dataframe for which I want to extract the numbers from the beginning of string. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
Test = {'Text': ['/CY1000 HZ 23 Street Arizona','/3456 BZ 33 Rue Avenue France','/2222 6th Street Madrid', np.nan],
    'Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(Test,columns= ['Text', 'Price'])
```

and I want to put 1000,3456,2222,NaN on to another column and have the rest of the text in another column to have

```
Test = {'Text': ['/CY1000 HZ 23 Street Arizona','/3456 BZ 33 Rue Avenue France','/2222 6th Street Madrid', np.nan],
        'Text1': ['1000','3456','2222',np.nan],
    'Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000],
     'Text2': [ 'HZ 23 Street Arizona', 'BZ 33 Rue Avenue France','6th Street Madrid', 'Nan']}
df = pd.DataFrame(Test,columns= ['Text', 'Text1','Text2','Price'])
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This would get you the digits:

```
^(?:[^0-9]+)?([0-9]+)
```

And your desired data would be inside `\1`

https://regex101.com/r/i4YfeV/1

Comment: thanks, it works well but Is there any way also just to split and have Text1 as the way you did and another column which includes ['HZ 23 Street Arizona','BZ 33 Rue Avenue France','6th Street Madrid','Nan'] without the digits that we extracted?

Comment: @Yagmur Yes, I'm sure Python has a was to do that but I'm not a Python programmer. You should be able to extract the number and put it in a dataframe and then use some sort of replace and save the remainder into a separate dataframe

Answer (score 1):

```
Test = {'Text': ['/CY1000 HZ 23 Street Arizona','/3456 BZ 33 Rue Avenue France','/2222 6th Street Madrid', np.nan],
    'Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(Test,columns= ['Text', 'Price'])

vals= []
for x in df.Text:
    if x is np.nan:
        x=""
    num = re.findall(r'\d+',x)
    if len(num)>0:
        vals.append(num[0])
    else:
        vals.append(np.nan)

print(vals)

df['Text1'] = vals
print(df)
```

Output:

```
['1000', '3456', '2222', nan]
                            Text  Price Text1
0   /CY1000 HZ 23 Street Arizona  22000  1000
1  /3456 BZ 33 Rue Avenue France  25000  3456
2        /2222 6th Street Madrid  27000  2222
3                            NaN  35000   NaN
```

**[EDIT]**
If for regex expression you can use this:

```
'/?([A-Z]+)?([0-9]+){1}'
```

and the match will be in group 2 i.e /2.

**[EDIT2]**
If for regex expression you can use this to extract only address(Based on comment):

```
'/?([A-Z]+)?([0-9]+){1} ([0-9A-Za-z ]+)'
```

and the match will be in group 3 i.e /3.

Comment: Thanks so much. I s there any way also just to split and have Text1 as the way you did and another column which includes ['HZ 23 Street Arizona','BZ 33 Rue Avenue France','6th Street Madrid','Nan'] without the digits that we extracted?

Comment: '/?([A-Z]+)?([0-9]+){1} ([0-9A-Za-z ]+)' use this regex and extract group 3 i.e /3.

Comment: Thanks. However, if I have a row ' Name_A Ltd 3 no. Street Madrid' instead of ''/2222 6th Street Madrid'' then your code gives me 3 instead of NaN. However, it shouldnt give me that since that row doesnt start with 3. Do you know if there is a way to solve that issue?

Comment: I didn't get exactly what you are trying to tell, can you  elaborate it a bit more.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. i.e if my 'Text': ['/CY1000 HZ 23 Street Arizona','/3456 BZ 33 Rue Avenue France', ' Name_A Ltd 3 no. Street Madrid', np.nan] and do the regex as you suggested I will get [('CY', '1000', 'HZ 23 Street Arizona'), ('', '3456', 'BZ 33 Rue Avenue France'), ('', '3', 'Madrid'), nan]. However, I would like to have 1000,3456, Nan, Nan in my group 2 and in my group 3 I should have 'HZ 23 Street Arizona', 'BZ 33 Rue Avenue France', 'Name_A Ltd 3 no. Street Madrid',nan. Is it abit clearer?

Comment: Yes it is clear, thanks.  Does the character '/' comes before the four digit number, if the four digit number exists?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204874/discussion-between-strange-and-yagmur).

Answer (score 0):

You this code to extract number from string.

```py
    import re
    Test = {'Text': ['/CY1000 HZ 23 Street Arizona','/3456 BZ 33 Rue Avenue France','/2222 6th Street Madrid'],
        'Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000]}
    print(Test['Text'])
    temp = re.findall(r'^(?:[^0-9]+)?([0-9]+)', Test['Text'][0]) 
    print(temp)
    temp1 = re.findall(r'^(?:[^0-9]+)?([0-9]+)', Test['Text'][1]) 
    print(temp1)
```

Output will be :

```
[1000]
[3456]
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I s there any way also just to split and have Text1 as the way you did and another column which includes ['HZ 23 Street Arizona','BZ 33 Rue Avenue France','6th Street Madrid','Nan'] without the digits that we extracted?

Comment: you want to handle NAN also ?

Comment: Yes, since there could be a case where it wont start with digits. Thanks